# How to add keywords (syntax highlighting) to language extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Does anyone know of a way to add new keywords (for syntax highlighting) to a language extension from the marketplace? Specifically I'm using the PL/SQL extension but it's missing some keywords I'd like to add (like BETWEEN, GREATEST, LEAST) without recreating the whole language extension myself. It was pretty easy to associate new file extensions with it but I haven't been able to find any documentation on adding keywords like you can in Notepad++ for example.

Is there documentation somewhere I missed?

Comment: you mean syntax highlighting?

Comment: @bolov yeah, adding keywords for the syntax highlighting.

Comment: [edit] your question to clarify this. As it is worded it sounds like you want to change the language itself.

Comment: Sure, I could see that. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Add the keywords to the language's syntax file**

- Open the extension's folder

  - **Windows**: `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions\casian.plsql-0.0.2`
  - **Mac/Linux**: `$HOME/.vscode/extensions/casian.plsql-0.0.2`
- Open the `.tmLanguage` file
- Go to the line which contains the highlighted keywords such as `select` and `from`.
- Add the missing keywords to the list and save the file
- Reload VSCode. Now the recently added keywords appear highlighted
- Backup the `.tmLanguage` file. Your changes will be overwritten when there is an update for the plugin.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Looked in AppData where things like this are normally stored, now it makes sense why I didn't find it. It's a shame that this can't just be a permanent addition...